# How to handle apostrophe in requests to typeahead jquery function

Tags: jquery, json

I am using the JQuery Type ahead function to match and show suggestions for employer names by using three characters user has entered. But if user enters apostrophe(') as the employer names sometimes has apostrophe in it (eg: O'lando) this function is not working, please let me know how to handle apostrophe in this jquery function.

```
 $('.mypage').typeahead({        
        minLength: 3,
        items: 'all',

    source: function (request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/AutoCom.asmx/MatchEmployers",
            data: "{ 'employerName': '" + request + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) { --------
```

Comment: There is one tricky way is that you can replace " ' " (Single Quote) by placing another single quote before that single quote for that you have to check each time before sending to REQUEST object,i mean at your Codeside.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the web method in code behind is not even being hit when i have apostrophe in request. The JQuery function stops working at all when i enter apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I bump into this "bug" (not sure about this). I try in some ways, but the only one that seems to work is to use the equivalent html ascii code, in my case ' for the simple "straight quote mark / apostrophe".
I wrote just few lines in php to avoid this apostrophe in the title location inside my json.
Works fine also, with the typeahead script that use an array (in my case php writes the corresponding javascript array).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to send JSON to your AJAX URL, but you're constructing the string to send manually. You're just concatenating the strings together, so that if there's a quote in your request (as in "O'lando"), it ends up with something like

```
data: "{ 'employerName': 'O'lando' }",
```

Which can't work because the quotation marks aren't right.

When you want to construct JSON to send somewhere, don't try to build it yourself, let the browser do it for you. You want something like:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'employerName': request  }),
```

The [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function takes a JavaScript object and handles all the escaping needed for it to be a pure JSON string, which can then be used in a web request or wherever you need to it be a string instead of an object.